# Printing columns in the output file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I got the output for the last command using the below command

```
last -w -F | awk '{print $1","$3","$5$6$7$8","$11$12$13$14","$15}' | tac | tr ',' '\t'
```

Now for the same output i want to add the below column names and then copy to csv file or xls file.

Can someone help me out here.

Column Names

```
USERNAME
HOSTNAME
LOGIN_TIME
LOGOUT_TIME
DURATION
```

Output looks like this

```
oracle localhost 2015 2.30
root   localhost 2014 2.30
```

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Your awk statement produces five columns but the sample output only shows four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
last -w -F | awk '{print $1,$3,$5$6$7$8,$11$12$13$14,$15} END{print "USERNAME\tUSERNAME\tHOSTNAME\tHOSTNAME\tLOGIN_TIME\tLOGIN_TIME\tLOGOUT_TIME\tLOGOUT_TIME DURATION"}' OFS='\t' | tac
```

I added the headings to the `END` statement in awk.  This way, after `tac` is run, the headings will be at the beginning.

I also set awk's OFS to a tab so that the tr step should no longer be needed.

I couldn't thoroughly test this because my `last` command apparently produces a different format than yours.

#### Writing to a file

To write the above output to a file, we use *redirection*: stdout is sent to a file:

```
last -w -F | awk '{print $1,$3,$5$6$7$8,$11$12$13$14,$15} END{print "USERNAME\tUSERNAME\tHOSTNAME\tHOSTNAME\tLOGIN_TIME\tLOGIN_TIME\tLOGOUT_TIME\tLOGOUT_TIME DURATION"}' OFS='\t' | tac >new.tsv
```

The above code produces a tab-separated file.  After selecting the options for tab-separated format, Excel should be able to read this file.

If one wants a comma-separated-file, then all we need to to is replace the `\t` by `,`:

```
last -w -F | awk '{print $1,$3,$5$6$7$8,$11$12$13$14,$15} END{print "USERNAME,USERNAME,HOSTNAME,HOSTNAME,LOGIN_TIME,LOGIN_TIME,LOGOUT_TIME,LOGOUT_TIME DURATION"}' OFS=',' | tac >new.csv
```

If I recall correctly, one can open this in excel with file->open->text file.

Comment: Thank You John,Can you please help me how to write this into CSV or excel file with the requested columns.

Comment: @KrupalPatel OK.  I added examples that used redirection of stdout to create a file.  I included code for both tab-separated-values and comma-separated-values.

Comment: Thank you john.Is there a way i can get serial numbers automatically in the csv file.

Comment: @KrupalPatel Probably.  Where are the serial numbers coming from?